# How can I pass environment variables to Jenkins Pipeline Tools section

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > JDK installation > I have added JDK7 and its name is oracle-7u80; Similarly under Maven installation, I have added Maven 3.5 install and named it mvn.

Now I am using the above two installs in the Pipeline script:

```
    pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'mvn'
        jdk 'oracle-7u80'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not want to hard code the jdk and Maven values in the Tools section in the pipeline. I want to pass these values via environment variables or properties so that I can manage them externally.

Is there a way to pass the values (mvn or oracle-7u80) that is defined to Maven and jdk in the tools using environment variables?

Like if I need to inject a value within Steps/Script section, in Jenkins pipeline, I can define globally in the environment variables or using Jenkins project
Configure
General
Check mark Prepare an environment for the run
Check mark Keep Jenkins environment variables
I can provide the environment variable in the properties content with Properties File definition.

My intention is to get a format like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven '${MVN_VERSION}'
        jdk '${ORACLE_VERSION'}
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
            
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_the value of Maven_"? The build output to `stdout`? What has the property file you define in _Properties File Path_ to do with "_the value of Maven_"?

Comment: Thank you for the response @GeroldBroser, I have updated my question with more clarity.

Comment: You ARE managing them externally. The tools you are specifying (man, oracle-7u80) are names of specific configurations. The tool path is set in the Global Tools Config page.  Just change the value them (external to your job) and you get the new value next pass. Also, even if this did work (as @gerold-broser disproved), you'd need to use double quotes, not single quotes for it to be interpolated. You can also override the tool locations at the node configuration level for each node .

Comment: @IanW I think Global Tool config is not what acm wants since this is (semi-)static as well. I think it's meant to be dynamic per-build, not dynamic for the entire project.

Comment: To each their own. We have many JDK options set, labeled jdk6, jdk,7 jdk8, openjdk8, openjdk11. Each is set to /apps/jdk/<something>/At the OS level, point (symlink to jdk8 -> jdk1.8.0_291 and can switch to jdk1.8 -> jdk1.8.0_301 when we isntall, so user doesn't know. On Win nodes, we override Tool location at Node level to E:\apps\jdk\<something>, and also use symlinks on WIN (`mklink /d`). Works for us. The other option we use is to leverage [maven toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html), but @acm didn't elaborate. Depends on acm's real needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipeline projects are often used with a `Jenkinsfile` (*Pipeline script from SCM* in the ***Pipeline*** → *Definition* drop-down list) to bind a source code version and its build configuration to each other for reproducable builds.

Injecting build tool versions from external before the build contradicts this idea.

I'm also not sure whether this is even possible conceptually since (environment) variables' values from external are set in `stages ... script` which is a totally different declaration branch than `tools`. But hey, it's called *declarative* pipeline, not imperative, so order shouldn't matter ... in theory. I'll give it a try.

For passing external values into internal variables in general see [*Pipeline: Nodes and Processes, sh: Shell Script*](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) and also the answer to the question [*How to access Shell variable value into Groovy pipeline script*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68748369/1744774).

##### Maven version injection try

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    tools {
        maven "${MVN_VERSION}"
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Try: Maven version injected') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.MVN_VERSION = sh script: 'echo "Maven 3.8.1"', returnStdout: true
                }
                echo "${MVN_VERSION}"                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### As expected:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Tool Install)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: MVN_VERSION for class: groovy.lang.Binding
...
```

Another idea that came into my mind is to make this project parameterized with two parameters (e.g. `MVN_GLOBAL_TOOL_NAME`, `JDK_GLOBAL_TOOL_NAME`) via *Choice parameter* s, for instance, and this works:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    tools {
        maven "${MVN_GLOBAL_TOOL_NAME}" // coming from parameterized project's build parameter
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Maven tool as build parameter') {
            steps {
                echo "MVN_GLOBAL_TOOL_NAME=${MVN_GLOBAL_TOOL_NAME}"                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### Console Outpout

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Tool Install)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Maven version as build parameter)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
MVN_GLOBAL_TOOL_NAME=Maven 3.8.1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

See also `${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/api/`:

> #### Perform a build
>
> If the build has parameters, post to this URL [Link note: `${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/buildWithParameters`] and provide the parameters as form data.

See also: `${JENKINS_URL}/env-vars.html/`.

Comment: I tried adding a parameter to the project for maven and that ran the project by injecting the parameter value to the tools as desired. Thank you Gerold!