# How to let Jenkins pipeline build only for given branches

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In the following pipeline, I am trying to check out only develop branch to build the given project. How do I make sure that the pipeline only run develop, master and release branches?
Should I add separate stages for master branch and another for release branch. Instead I am trying to let this pipeline build only when there are changes in develop or master or release branches and ignore building for any other branches.

In Jenkins > Freestyle project > Source code management > Git > User can enter specific branches in Branch specifier. How can I implement similar one using pipeline?

```
pipeline {
agent any
tools {
    maven "${mvnHome}"
    jdk  'jdk8'
}
stages {
stage('Checkout project') {
    steps {
        git branch: 'develop',
            credentialsId: 'someid',
            url: 'https://project.git'
    }
}

    stage('build') {
        steps {
            sh '''
             mvn clean deploy
            '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to this (see for that below) but the content of your `${mvnHome}` is NOT your Maven home dir but [like in this answer from me to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68763377/1744774) Maven's _Global Tool Configuration_ name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can write conditions in groovy to do this using **when** statement. Something like this

```
stage('build'){
  when {
    expression {
      env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop' || env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'
      }
  }
 steps{
   script{
   sh 'mvn clean deploy '
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it simpler with [`when { branch ... }`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions)?

Comment: Can't we have the branch condition for all the stages at one place instead of having this condition at every stage?

Comment: This answer did not work for me. Skipped when branch is master.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *Multibranch Pipeline* project and add at its ***Branch Sources*** → ***Git*** → *Behaviours*:

- ***Filter by name (with regular expression)***

  > A [Java regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to restrict the names. Names that do not match the supplied regular expression will be ignored.
  > **NOTE: this filter will be applied to all branch like things, including change requests**

- **Filter by name (with wildcards)**

  - Include

  > Space-separated list of name patterns to consider. You may use `*` as a wildcard; for example: `master release*`
  > **NOTE: this filter will be applied to all branch like things, including change requests**

  - Exclude

  > Space-separated list of name patterns to ignore even if matched by the includes list. For example: `release alpha-* beta-*`
  > **NOTE: this filter will be applied to all branch like things, including change requests**