# Can a Groovy variable be assigned value from within a shell script? [JENKINSFILE]

Tags: shell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

**Scenario:**

I have a **for-in** loop written in groovy in Jenkinsfile. For every iteration of this loop i want to assign a value from within a shell script which runs(aws cli commond) on every iteration to a Groovy list/map variable outside the loop.

Example code snippet:

```
def functionName() {
  
   Groovy variable(list/map type);

   for in loop {
    
      sh """
          Groovy variable = value
      """
   
   } 
 

}
```

Can anyone provide an example or explain how can this be done?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: `groovy_variable = sh(script: "echo value", returnStdout: true).toString().trim()`

Comment: So the entire script should be assigned to the groovy_variable and echo only the value which I need is it? Because I have other aws cli commands running inside the script.

Comment: The entire script output should be assigned to only one variable (all command output)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Shell variable value into Groovy pipeline script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68748267/how-to-access-shell-variable-value-into-groovy-pipeline-script)

Comment: Yes it does, but what happens if there are multiple echo inside the script? I'm logging few error messages as well from the shell script. Is there any way I can pick one particular echo value? 
Please consider me a beginner in this.

Comment: AshayFernandes Redirect all `echo`s to a log file. `tee` the particular one to the log file (and `stdout` implicitely). See also [How to return stdout and stderr together with the status from a Jenkins Pipeline sh script step](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68967642/1744774).